# IP addresses utility library for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using NPM module `ip` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip) in an Angular app to do some parsing/comparation of IP addresses. Everything was working fine, but when I try to build the application for production using `ng build --prod --aot`, the compiler complains with the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ip/lib/ip.js Module not found: 
Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/fel/Documentos/proyectos/IPGes/node_modules/ip/lib
```

It seems that the error comes because it tries to use the module `os`, which is only available in a node.js environment, not in the browser.

Does anybody know if there's a workaround that enables to use the `ip` npm module in an Angular compiled app?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Requests to find libraries are off-topic on SO. This library appears to be specific NodeJS not browser--making it work on the browser might be possible depending on what it uses "os" for; didn't dig.

Comment: Sorry to ask for a library, I was wondering if someone that reads this question has had the same problem as me and could suggest me an alternative. I'll edit it to remove this part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `ip` library is a NodeJs specific library since it has a dependency on `os`. In some cases, you can have some luck using [browserfy](http://browserify.org/) to make your node packages work in the browser. However, I don't think it'll work with this one.

I would suggest moving this logic to your server. If you're using node, just add the package there and surfaced an API endpoint to post an IP Address. Thay way, you can use the library as you wish.

The only reason why this works locally while running in Dev is that Angular is running a node server at that point. Once you bundle everything up, it's just a bunch of bundled HTML and JS.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case anyone has the same trouble, I dropped the `ip` library (which is a great tool, but for Node projects) and I used `ipaddr.js` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipaddr.js), which has all the methods I've needed in the application.

Cheers,